# How to disable the DHCP client in Windows 10 Enterprise completely?

Tags: windows-10, dhcp

I have a PC with Windows 10 Enterprise x64. The PC has 2 physical network interfaces; let's name them NIC1 and NIC2.

I have disabled NIC2, using the Windows UI, and I have removed the network cable from NIC2.

I have assigned a **static IP to NIC1.** NIC1 is connected to a switch.

There is no other network adapter present or configured.

Windows is still sending DHCP client queries, approximately every 5 seconds. Could somebody please explain why this happens and how I can stop it?

My attention was drawn to that issue when I investigated the firewall logs **on another machine** in the same network. That is, I am seeing those requests on other PCs, without capturing them on the source PC. This means that I am absolutely sure that the source PC actually puts them onto the wire and sends them out via NIC1, which is the only active network interface.

I know that I can stop and disable the DHCP client service, which would probably solve the issue. However, in my experience, disabling services is sometimes not wise, because it can cause collateral damage at unexpected places. Furthermore, I'm eager to learn why Windows behaves like that, and would prefer to understand and eliminate the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Through which adapter(s) are sent these DHCP requests ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Well, I actually don't know. However, since NIC1 is the only adapter where a cable is attached, and since there are no wireless interfaces, it must be NIC1 which these requests are sent through, although NIC1 is configured with a static IPv4 configuration. I should have written **that I see those DHCP requests in *other* machine's firewall logs;** that is, I don't record / investigate them on the source machine, but on another PC, which means that I am absolutely sure that they exist and are put on the wire. I'll add that to my question in a few seconds.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's clearly the adapter that is enabled.

Comment: See [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45785cf6-b041-453b-b9e2-21387c42c7ec/dhcp-requests-sent-on-nic-with-static-ip-address?forum=winserverPN).

Comment: Thank you very much again. However, the system in question is a client system, not a server, without RRAS running. Probably Windows is using DHCP for more things than assigning IP addresses. I will now probably disable the DHCP client service and see whether there are side effects.